# What is the difference between using the -m switch and __main__.py file in a package - as both allow to run file without the need to specify .py?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between using the `-m` switch and using `__main__.py` file in a package - as both allow to run file without the need to specify .py?

Comment: `-m` can be used with any importable "thing", not just packages. And there is an obvious difference between `python3 -m my_package` and `python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/my_package`.

Comment: Can you explain in an answer please